# Emissive material not visible through glass on Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Hi there i’ve been playing around in eevee with frosted glass and diffusers for lights. I seem to be running into an issue whereby the emissive material is being occluded by the glass shader at a certain point.

I’m not sure if this is a limitation of rasterization over ray tracing but it just seems to cutoff when the camera gets to a particular point (see cycles render fot the result I am after).

i’ve tried adjusting the refraction settings and adding in reflection cubemap but doesn’t seem to help, has anyone run into similar issues?

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found glass shaders to be not so useful in EEVEE, so I save them for Cycles if I need them. Instead, try using a node arrangement such as this. I tinted the glass green to show that it's actually tinted, and I put a light bulb (on the front side) to show it's actually glass (reflective AND transparent). Pay attention to the blend modes on the right.

[image: Glass]

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the record, now that I look at your photos a bit closer, it looks like the cutoff may be caused by the IOR of the glass shader, combined with the angle of the "top" of your glasses, but I can't be sure. Either way, this should rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

With EEVEE set as render engine under the *Material Properties* tab create new material and select *Alpha Blend* for *Blend Mode* and set value of alpha less than 1, this would be your glass material. If you want it look more like glass use some noise texture for roughness.

[image: Alpha transparency]